# Resize dialog to wrap rotated widget

Tags: android, android-layout, android-dialogfragment, android-seekbar

I have a simple alert dialog with a custom view. The view simply contains a seekbar, I want a  vertical seekbar so I set rotation to 270. The problem is the dialog is still wrapping around the seekbar as if it's horizontal (best seen when enabling layout bounds - see picture). How could I resolve this?

[image]

Comment: This seems strange to me. Could you please given some more informations on why you want a vertical search bar ?

Comment: @antoine-marques Hi, I want a vertical seekbar because the other stock camera apps on the phone use the same. I'd preferably like to keep a similar ux if possible.

Comment: I mean, is the text written vertically, or is it just the orientation of the activity that changes ? Usually camera are mounted in landscape mode, so activities involving camera usually run in landscape oientation (whereas normal activties often running portrait), given the impression that the text field is rotated, while it is the entire activity that's *rotated*